# A classical optimization problem - what's the *most* general approach?

Tags: inequality, optimization

Consider the following problem:

A factory has to produce some amount of a certain *mixture*, which is made of three substances, **A**, **B** and **C**. This *mixture* should contain at least 30 kg of substance **A**, at least 20 kg of substance **B** and *at most* 25 kg of substance **C**. The factory is going to use two intermediate products **P1** and **P2**. Intermediate product **P1** is 70% substance **A**, 10% substance **B** and 20% substance **C**, whereas intermediate product **P2** -- 30% of **A**, 30% of **B** and of **C**. The price of one kilogramme of these intermediate products is 25 dollars and 15 dollars, respectively.

The question is: **how much of intermediate products should the factory buy to fulfill the requirements and minimize the cost?**

My approach is as follows: let's denote the amount of intermediate products **P1** and **P2** by $X$ and $Y$ respectively. The cost of the purchase is then:
$$ 25\cdot X+15\cdot Y$$ 
We have to find the minimum of this function with the following constraints:
$$0.7\cdot X+0.3\cdot Y\ge 30$$
$$0.1\cdot X+0.3\cdot Y\ge 20$$
$$0.2\cdot X+0.3\cdot Y\le 25$$

My question is: *how* does one determine the minimum of such function knowing the constraints? Is there any method other than ''plot the inequalities and try to fit the line''?

Comment: Certainly -- [Linear programming: Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Algorithms). Start with the classic [simplex method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm).

Comment: Well, keep in mind it has to be done on paper. No acces to computer.

Comment: Anything that can be done by computer can be done on paper, it just takes a little longer. There is no closed-form formula for solving linear programming problems, if that's what you're expecting. You have to use an iterative algorithm such as the simplex method.

Comment: Actually a plot in this case is the simplest way - draw the polygon boundary for the feasible region, check the corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's scale the numbers to avoid fractions:
\begin{align}
\min\quad &25x + 15y\\
\mathrm{s.t.}\quad &7x+3y\geqslant30 \tag 1\\
\quad &x + 3y \geqslant20 \tag 2\\
\quad &2x+3y\leqslant 25 \tag 3\\
\quad &x,y\geqslant0.
\end{align}
If $x=0$, from constraint $(1)$ we see that $y\geqslant 10$, which violates constraint $(3)$. If $y=0$, then from constraint $(2)$ we see that $x\geqslant 20$, which again violates constraint $(3)$. Because there are two variables, there must be at least two binding constraints. There are three possibilities - $(1)$ and $(2)$, $(1)$ and $(3)$, and $(2)$ and $(3)$. Only the first is a feasible solution, and hence we solve
\begin{align}
7x + 3y&=30\\
x+3y&=20
\end{align}
which yields $x=\frac53$, $y=\frac{55}9$ for an objective value of $\frac{400}3$.